# Elementary Number Theory: Cubic Congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, polynomial-congruences

Solve $5x^3 -2x + 1 \equiv 0 $ mod 243.

We're using Hensel Lifting theorem to solve. I am trying to use the example we did in class but I am not following. I know we need to the dericative and find the prime factorization of 243.

Comment: You've given an expression, not an equation. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you for commenting on that. I had not realized I did not write the entire problem down.

Comment: Have you found the derivative and prime factorization of 243?

Comment: Since $243=3^5$, a solution of that equation would have to satisfy also $5x^3-2x+1\equiv0\pmod{3}$. But trying $x=0,1,2$ you see that none of them are solutions. Alternatively $5x^3-2x+1=3x^3+2(x-1)x(x+1)+1\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ because $(x-1)x(x+1)$ is the product of three consecutive numbers and therefore multiple of $3$, and so it $3x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll never solve this congruence modulo $3^5$, because there isn’t even a solution modulo $3$. For, over $\Bbb F_3$, your polynomial is $2x^3+x+1=-(x^3-x-1)$. Why? Because for $n\in\Bbb Z$, $n^3\equiv n\pmod3$, and as a *function* on $\Bbb F_3$, your polynomial is constant nonzero.